# Fedex Sandbox test integration not working

Tags: python

I tried to test fedex sandbox . to get the auth token https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token
and given grant_type=csp_credentials&client_id=Client_ID&client_secret=Client_secret&child_Key=Child_key&child_secret=Child_Secret

below is response

The given grant_type is not supported. Please modify your request and try again.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include relevant parts of the code and ensure your grant_type is valid for the request you're making.

Comment: Just trying to access from post man. How to get grant_type for my account. https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

payload =
"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxxx&client_secret=xxxxx" this is enough to get the oauth token. child key and child secret keys are optional.
these keys can be get it after we logged in developer fedex portal

Ref:https://plumrocket.com/docs/magento-order-status-shipping-tracking/v1/integrations/fedex-api